# Updating deprecated methods

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache

I'm updating an old bit of custom Joomla plugin, and there's a deprecated line saying `JResponse::allowCache(false);` -- what's the "right" way to handle this for Joomla 3.x compatibility?

Also, perhaps this could be a separate question, but is there a way to set key => value pairs manually in the Joomla cache? For example, this plugin does lookups for US states. So if it's displaying a lot of information, it has to hit the DB over and over looking for the state abbreviation, when we could simply cache this response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JResponse::allowCache(false);` replacement is

```
JFactory::getApplication()->allowCache(false);
```

To set `key => value` cache items:

```
// Get cache instance
$cache = JFactory::getCache();

// Store in cache
$cacheItemStored = $cache->store($value, $key, $group = null); // boolean

// Get from cache
$value = $cache->get($key, $group = null);
```

As you can see you can set optional `$group`. This is useful for cleaning all cache in specific group or not in specific group.

For example:

```
$cache->clean('groupName'); // will clean all cache IN "groupName" group
$cache->clean('groupName', 'notgroup'); // will clean all cache NOT IN "groupName" group
```

Comment: @Rene-- thanks! If you have a moment, could you explain a bit about how the cache `callback` type is used?

Comment: It's actually nice feature and way longer story for comment. But in short, you can cache calls to functions or methods of classes. So if cache isn't expired, if will return cached data, therefore not hiting DB or API again. Pretty nice? :) You don't have to store it, just use `get` and it will store response automatically, if it dosen't exist. Example here: https://www.corephp.com/blog/implementing-joomlas-cache-callback-api/

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to bump this older question but the accepted response isn't totally correct.  Most everything in JResponse is replaced by a similarly named method call in JApplicationWeb instances (of which the CMS web application classes are).  See https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JResponse.html for more details.

So `JResponse::allowCache(false);` is replaced by `JFactory::getApplication()->allowCache(false);`.

Comment: Thanks Michael-- the Joomla docs are saying to use `JApplicationWeb::allowCache(false);`, though this throws a warning since you're calling a non-static method statically (found here: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/deprecated.html)

Comment: Thanks Michael for pointing this out. You are absolutely right, I somehow mixed it up with regular cache. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user101289 That's right.  The documentation doesn't explicitly say how to access it, but it does at least reference the new method you should use.  Generally the context is `JFactory::getApplication()->allowCache()` but that assumes a lot too (though in 99% of cases because Joomla and extensions don't do well with non web applications you're fine).